# Understanding Incorrect Permissions for Instagram API

Tags: python, instagram, instagram-api

I've written a python script to use the Instagram API to find all the media associated with a given user. This user is one of the users that I follow on Instagram.

When running this line of code...

```
api.user_recent_media(user_id=user, count=sys.maxint)
```

...I get the following error:

```
(400) APINotAllowedError-you cannot view this resource
```

Why am I getting this error if I'm querying a user that I follow? What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Are you properly authorized to use the api for that user id?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an `access_token` generated for your account.

Basically the Instagram permissions for the Users endpoint works like this:

- If the target user is public, you can query that user's info and media with a `client_id` without the need for any authentication.
- If the target user is private, using the `client_id` will not work and you need to do [authentication](http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/#) and use the `access_token` from an authenticated user that follows that target user.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the wrong access token (from a different account).

Thanks!